# Google Mobile-Friendly test passed, yet page appears on Mobile Usability issues list

Tags: mobile, google-search-console

Google's webmaster tools is showing a large number of pages have mobile usability issues (see screenshot) yet once you click on the link and then click on "Check Live Version" (of the same page), it shows that everything is fine ("Page is mobile-friendly" in green). After resubmitting that page to the google indexer the page still appears to have issues a few weeks later.

[image]

It almost seems like a different algorithm is used to check mobile usability by the indexer and the Live tester.

[image]

Has anyone come across this issue? Any pointers as to how to reconcile these?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just got this reply from another forum:

"If the page passes the live test, there is nothing more you can do.

The report is slow to update at times, so might just be delayed."